# MQ Appliance CLOCK command - can't set time

Tags: ibm-mq

On a v 9.0.4 MQ Appliance, I'm trying to setup the proper time.  The zone is correct, but the  time is like 12 hours off.  NTP is disabled.

```
mqa# config
Global configuration mode
mqa(config)# ntp-service
Modify NTP Service configuration

mqa(config ntp-service)# show
 admin-state disabled 
 refresh-interval 900 Seconds
mqa(config ntp-service)# exit
mqa(config)# clock 14:08:00

% Date '14:08:00' is not valid
```

Setting the DATE with the clock command works fine - but setting the TIME with the clock command returns "Date '...' is not valid every time.  Is there something obvious were doing wrong?  I really don't want to continue doing other setup until this gets figured out...

Comment: Based on the IBM Knowledge Center the command appears to be valid.  I would suggest you open a PMR with IBM to ask why it is NOT working.

Comment: Can you try runjning the command outside of config mode?

Comment: `mqa# clock 14:08:00` instead of `mqa(config)# clock 14:08:00`.

Comment: i did ... no luck .. as it turned out, I re-visited the NTP service option and it seems to be working now ( i think i may have had a Firewall issue there) ... so the time is at least correct now... without having to use the command.